# «Чёрти-что» и «чёрти-как»

Tags: словообразование, местоимения, слитно-раздельно-дефис

Чёрти-что, чёрти-как, чёрти-кто, чёрти-где — это все местоимения? Неопределенные?
Чем является *чёрти-*? И как правильно пишется? (Встречала много вариантов: чёрт-те что, чёрте-что, чёрте что...)
С какими еще местоимениями можно употребить?

Comment: Вряд ли Вы встречали в литературе всё, что написали, так как есть норма русского языка на эту тему.

Comment: @Варяг-91, напомните правило. Тем более станно это читать в сочетании с утверждением, что **всё** это "местоимения". Особенно (черти-где и черти-как).

Comment: Хотя, снимаю. Людмила ответила полностью. Хотя местоимения в роли наречия - это все равно круто.)))

Answer (score 7):

Это местоименные фразеологизмы со значением неопределённости — сочетания слов без грамматической связи между ними: черт(-)те кто, черт(-)те что, черт(-)те какой, черт(-)те где, черт(-)те как, черт(-)те когда, черт(-)те откуда, черт(-)те сколько и др. Например:

*Молодой еще был, глупый, совал нос **черт те куда*** (фразеологизм в роли неопределённого наречия). В. Кунин. Кыся.

*Вокруг валяется по межам и канавам **черт те что*** (фразеологизм в роли неопределённого местоимения). В. Лихоносов. Наш маленький Париж.

*— Ну, это другое дело, — сконфузился Михась. — А бомбу вот такую вытаскивать из болота — это же **черт-те что**. И вы их, значит, три штуки вытащили?* П. Нилин. Через кладбище.

*— Штаб армии искал. Какой-то дурак сказал мне, что он в Банном овраге. Я и попер туда. А там, знаешь, что делается? За три шага ни черта не видно. Дым, пыль — **черт-те что**...* В. Некрасов. В окопах Сталинграда.

Все подобные фразеологизмы построены по модели «сущ. в имен. пад. + частица *те* + местоименный компонент».

Говорить о норме написания сложно, потому что это грубо-просторечные выражения. В словарях зафиксировано чаще дефисное написание.

- [черт-те что | ideographic.academic.ru](http://ideographic.academic.ru/4636/%D1%87%25)
- [Чёрт-те что | phraseology.academic.ru](http://phraseology.academic.ru/13952/%D0%A7%25)
- [Черт | enc-dic.com](http://enc-dic.com/kuzhecov/Chert-67304.html)

Но можно объяснить и раздельное. Иногда фразеологизм "черт те что" употребляется в роли гневного  междометия, где "те" явно частица, а у Розенталя есть примечание: Дефис не пишется в выражениях типа: *Вот те раз! Чёрт те знает! Я те покажу!* (*те* — сокращение от тебя, тебе). Это как раз такое выражение.

*Чёрти-что, чёрти-как, чёрти-кто, чёрти-где* тоже пишут, но это уже имитация произношения, как, например, "щас" вместо "сейчас".

Вероятно, сначала было *чёрт ти* (*ти* — старославянская энклитическая форма тебЪ). Переход в "чёрт-те" произошёл, вероятно, после того, как энклитики исчезли из языка и "ти" стало восприниматься одновременно как усилительная частица и как усечённое "тебе".

Так что обе формы (**чёрт-те что** и **чёрт те что**) имеют право на существование, а остальные написания "произносительные", для стилизации под просторечия.

Comment: На одном из форумов автор похожего вопроса интересовался семантикой подобных выражений, но все обсуждали только их форму, про значение так никто и ничего не рассказал. Все междометия, связанные с чёртом,  более-менее ясны по смыслу, но что дословно означает "чёрт-те что, чёрт-те как"? Чёрт тебе что? Не очень понятно. И еще одно выражение неясно по  содержанию - чёрта с два.  Почему именно  цифра два?

Comment: "чёрта с два" = "как бы не так!"., "этого не может быть".
По суеверным народным представлениям черти могут множиться, раздваиваясь,  в представлениях о чертях действует оппозиция "чет - нечет".  "два" - число четное, бесовское, "нечистое". Оно усиливает категоричность отказа.

Comment: Здесь же "те" уже частица, лексическое значение привязывается только к словам чёрт и что.Что указывает на неодушевлённость, а чёрт -для того, чтобы заявить о некой неопределённости, чуждой действительности. Этот фразеологизм - усечённая форма выражения, что-то вроде "чёрт знает, что тебе видится", т.е. никто не знает, что это такое, что-то ненормальное.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: @Людмила Красиво, исчерпывающе. Подправила только оформление (постаралась сделать ещё _красившее_) — надеюсь, Вы не против.

Comment: Нет, не против, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

> чёрт-те что, чёрте-что, чёрте что?..

***"Русским орфографическим словарём"*** кодифицирован первый из этих вариантов.

**См.:** [чертте* | gramota.ru](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B5*&all=x)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

АКАДЕМИЯ НАУК СССР
ИНСТИТУТ РУССКОГО ЯЗЫКА

РУССКАЯ ГРАММАТИКА

§ 1702. ...К числу междометий со специализированными семантическими функциями относятся: ай-ай-ай, ба, боже сохрани, бог с тобой, браво, бррр, вона (прост.), вот те крест, вот те христос, вот тебе на, вот тебе раз, вот так так, гм, господь с тобой, да ну, дьявол, ей, ей-богу, ей-же-ей, ей право (устар.), еще чего, и-и-и (и-и полно), как бы не так, как же, на-поди, на тебе (нате), ну да (ну да, как же), ну и ну, ну уж, однако, ой-ли, ох, поди ж ты, подумаешь, помилуйте, скажите (скажите на милость), слава богу, то-то (вот то-то, то-то и оно-то), тю, тьфу, увы, ф-фе, фи, фрр, фу, ха, х-хе, хи, хо, ужо (прост.), упаси бог, ура, **черт, черт-те что,** что за черт, черта с два, чтоб тебя, сейчас (в произношении - щас), эва, эк, эка, эх, эхма.

Answer (score 1):

Ч. знает что или чёрт-те что! (восклицание, выражающее возмущение; разг.). Чёрт-те кто (что, какой) (неизвестно кто, что, какой; разг. неодобр. и пренебр.). Чёрт-те где (куда, откуда, когда, зачем, почему, отчего) (неизвестно где, куда, откуда и т. д.; разг. неодобр.)  Это из Толкового словаря русского языка Ожегова и Шведовой. Подобное объяснение встречается и других изданиях.